# Accessing arrays(hashmap) in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im populating my hashmap like this

```
var temp = ${task.get(i).id};
wf.map[temp]=${task.get(i).isConnected()};
```

While accessing the map, Im accessing it in this way

```
   var temp = taskId.value;
   var connected= this.map[temp];
```

Here, im getting connected as undefined. 
In my case, I get temp = `"00000114000000000002"`. Even accessing `this.map["00000114000000000002"}` gives me same problem.

Instead if I access like this `this.map[00000114000000000002]` , it works absolutely fine.

I tried to typecast temp to number, int , even then no luck.

How to deal with this issue?

Comment: `${task.get(i).id}` -- I 'm pretty sure this syntax does not do what you think it does. It does not even compile.

Comment: You could try to console.log the entire object to see what the content is. Make sure to remember that the maximum int in js is 2,147,483,647 and ints prefixed with 0's will lose them.

Comment: That part is some thing to do with struts, just populating the variables, Im pretty sure there is no problem while populating the values.

Comment: What's `wf` (from line 2)? Could you perhaps use your browser's "View Page Source" option to see what JS is generated after the server-side `${}` stuff is done and add that information to the question? (Or at least add the appropriate tag to your question - "struts", is it?) @Jon - it's unexplained server-side code.

Comment: If you convert the string to number the starting zeros will disappear.  That could explain the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `var temp = "${task.get(i).id}";` to be sure it is a string when you create the property? If it's a numeric literal some browsers will take the leading zeros to mean the number is octal, so then if `taskId.value` is actually a string the value will be different.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, your guess is correct, that is what happening here , Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. (And note that even for browsers that don't assume octal they will still drop the leading zeros in between parsing the numeric literal and using it as an object key.)